# how to pass array to mvc using ajax in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How to pass array in mvc to store in sql server? I need to save every questions's score, so I using ajax and jquery to do it, but it only save one data of list array. The variable of array is `result` that need to assign in `eachscore` .Here my code.

**class**

```
  public partial class Score
    {
        public int idScore { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdMaterial { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> score { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> eachscore { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Learning Learning { get; set; }
    }
```

**Ajax**

```
function showScore(data, id, ...result) {
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Home/InsertScore",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data:
            { "score": score, "status": 1, "IdMaterial": id, "eachscore": result}           
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult InsertScore([Bind(Include = "idScore,date,status,IdMaterial, score, username,eachscore")] Score s)
        {
            if (Session["UserName"] != null)
            {
                var user = Session["UserName"].ToString();
                s.username = user;
                db.Scores.Add(s);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Array in AJAX Request

```
 var ScoreArray= [];
```

Push a data using For loop.

```
ScoreArray.push({
         idScore  : 1,
         score    : 10,
         Others key 

      });
```

Ajax Pass array

```
data: "{ 'lstScoreArray':" + JSON.stringify(ScoreArray) + "}"
```

Controller

public ActionResult InsertScore(List`<Score>` lstScoreArray)
{
Your code.....
}

Comment: but, the only array variable is `eachscore` , not all variable. `result` need assign in `eachscore`

Comment: I want only `eachscore` hold list array to save in database. The rest variable supposedly not contain in array.  from your suggestion, you store all variable in array.

Comment: It's like I pass other variable and also pass my variable array to mvc.

Comment: You have to pass eachscore using comma separated value. EX: 10,20,30etc...changes a code in Controller side. add new parameter it's call string eachscore. and split a string using comma and store value in DB using loop.